# insert array in other array in to a for loop,first result repeated

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a problem when inserting an array into another array in this loop:

```
function formToArray(frm){
    var sAux={};
    var AnnotationsQuestion={};
    var AllAnnotationsQuestion=[];

    for (i = 0; i < frm.length; i++) {

    //next line dont work
    sAux['question_id'] = frm[i].name.substring(13)
    sAux['answer']=frm[i].value;
    sAux['id']=0;
    AnnotationsQuestion['AnnotationsQuestion']=sAux;
    AllAnnotationsQuestion.push(AnnotationsQuestion);
    }

return AllAnnotationsQuestion 
}
```

this returns the first result repeated x times

example of a return value

```
[{'AnnotationsQuestion':{'question_id':4,'answer':
'AA'....}},{'AnnotationsQuestion':{'question_id':4,'answer':
'AA'....}}]
```

what is the problem of this loop?

Comment: You are not pushing a new object to `AllAnnotationsQuestion` on each iteration, rather a reference to the **same** object. Therefore, all elements of the returned array have the same value. If you do `var sAux = {}` at the beginning of your `for` loop, it should create a new object for that iteration, and then you will get unique values.

Comment: Yes, I also thought the same but putting *Saux var* = {}, at the beginning of each iteration, I got the same result

Comment: I do hope it was `var sAux = {};` and not `Saux var = {};`... Anyway, look at the answer by @mplungjan, it's much cleaner.

Comment: yes it is var sAux = {}; im sorry.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want the function to do; can you post your objects and what you'd like the result to look like?

Comment: I see. Yes, I'm sorry. The same object argument goes for `AnnotationsQuestion` as well. Once again, what you're pushing is a reference to a single object. Naturally, values are same across the board. You would have to do `var AnnotationsQuestion = {};` at the beginning of each iteration, along with `var sAux = {};`. Check http://jsfiddle.net/rtSYC/3/.

Comment: For some reason this line does not work for me *AllAnnotationsQuestion.push({'AnnotationsQuestion' : sAux });* , but thanks

Comment: It's working perfectly in the fiddle... Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much safer and readable

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/m4rW6/)

```
function formToArray(frm){
  var AllAnnotationsQuestion=[];

  for (var i = 0; i < frm.length; i++) {
    AllAnnotationsQuestion.push({
      'AnnotationsQuestion': {
        'question_id': frm[i].name.substring(13),
        'answer': frm[i].value, 
        'id':0 
      }
    });
  }
  return AllAnnotationsQuestion; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I got this error with your solution 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : '

Comment: This error is the chrome browser, in this line *'AnnotationsQuestion': {*